# Blazor - Reflection issue

Tags: c#, reflection, blazor-webassembly

I'm trying to get the data values out of an object. I can get the properties from the Class just fine. But when I ask for the values, it fails. Any thoughts on why the `GetValues` line isn't working?

```
@inject HttpClient Http
@using System.Reflection

<p>@str</>

@code {
    public string? str;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        stats = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<Statistics[]>("sample-data/CoreDataCompany2023E.json");

        Type type = typeof(Statistics);

        var properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

        foreach (var prop in properties)
        {
            str += prop.GetValue(stats);
        }    
    }
}

@code{
    public class Statistics
    {
        public string Year { get; set; }  
        public int Volume { get; set; }
    };

Statistics[] stats = new Statistics[]
    {
        new Statistics
        {
            Year = "2023",
            Volume = 1225000
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Ty! Just did some edits.

Comment: Why are you using reflection if you know the properties of the type you are deserializing into (`Statistics`)?

Comment: Because ultimately I'm looking for the data of the property in the object. And reflection should be an easy way to get it via prop.GetValue(stats). This should return "2023" and 1,225,000.

Comment: The loop is handling the array. If I write str += prop.Name inside the loop - works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're deserializing into something strongly typed (an array of `Statistics`), then take advantage of that typing system to get the properties you want with compile time checks.

```
stats = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<Statistics[]>("sample-data/CoreDataCompany2023E.json");
foreach (var stat in stats)
{
    str += stat.Year;
    str += stat.Volume;
}
```

If you need to use reflection, then remember that the `stats` variable is an *array* of `Statistics`, but your `prop` loop variable represents a property of a *singular* `Statistics` instance. You need to loop though each element in the array, then for each element in the array, loop though each property that element has.

```
stats = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<Statistics[]>("sample-data/CoreDataCompany2023E.json");

Type type = typeof(Statistics);
var properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

foreach (var stat in stats)
{
    foreach (var prop in properties)
    {
        str += prop.GetValue(stat); // change this to "stat" (the loop var)
    }
}
```

But at that point, might be better to not use reflection.

Comment: I agree, I like your solution better. But still failing.

Comment: What do you mean by "failing"? Can you put a breakpoint down and walk through this code to inspect your variables' values? Is `stats` what you expect it to be? What does `GetValue` return?

Comment: I had to remove the @using System.Reflection. And then your solution worked great. Ty!!!